# How to move laravel project from windows to Linux?

Tags: linux, laravel, composer-php

Can anybody tell me which tips required to move a laravel project from windows to linux?
I installed a new project on linux and copied files separately but it says can't open required conroller( Controller Name ) file

Comment: Backup DB, Install local server, install composer, install laravel.  However, if you were smart in your laravel design you would have made a DB migration so you don't have to back it up unless you wanted the records.  If you wanted the records you can just backup the DB.  Copy the project folder and carry the contents to the new OS.  It's simple

Comment: You know what? i did everything required, even better than you wrote but each file gives a different error all of them are like: can't find or can't open.

Comment: Post screenshot of your error

Comment: I installed a new laravel project on my LAMP server and i copied view,controller,models separately but it says can't find this view or that view, or maybe can't open this controller, that controller.

Comment: Beware of lettercase in file names. Windows is case-insensitive, linux is very case-sensitive. Always use '/' in path names on windows. I develop on windows and host on linux and there are no major issues migrating either way.

Comment: also check your paths.php to make sure everything is referenced correctly.  Assuming you just copied it over it shouldn't be messed up.  But I'd double check.

Comment: First it couldn't open MainController.php than i created a new file and named it MainController.php than copied all the contents and replaced the file, problem solved and it's continuing this process to my all files and i did the same for all files and now it's a final error which im stacked in.

Comment: is there any command of composer for compiling the project at once?

Comment: If your paths are correctly setup @AkmalArzhang then you should not see /var/www/.... it should just say view[filename] not found

Comment: Yeah it says View [layouts.reg-layout] not found.

Comment: Just don't focus on error @Rafael buddy, if i remove the extends function from my view than after loging in it throws another not found.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the mighty [Laravel Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead) and you will never have a problem switching your host development environment from windows to linux to mac or back.

How to migrate to another development environment like laravel homestead:

- Install your new environment (e.g. laravel homestead)
- If you have a database (e.g. mysql db): backup your database
- Copy your whole laravel project directory from windows to your linux/homestead environment setup (if you clone from a git repository make sure that `composer.lock` is included in your git repo and run `composer install` after cloning.
- If you have a database:

  - Migrate your database with `artisan migrate` if you want a clean and empty database structure.
  - OR: Rebuild it from your backup. Make sure the database user/password specified in your laravel config exists in the new environment and has write access to your rebuild database.